# Is my interpretation of the expression on the expectation is a correct one?

Tags: probability-theory, notation

Consider the following expression

$$E_{x\sim p_{data}(x)}[ f(x) ] $$

I am understanding it as

1) if X is a collection of a discrete random variable $(X_1, X_2,......, X_n)$, and x is generated from X by a particular assignment of all random variables in the tuple

Then

$$E_{x\sim p_{data}(x)}[ f(x) ] = \sum\limits_{x} f(x) p_{data}(x) $$

2) if $X$ is a collection of a continuous random variable $(X_1, X_2,......, X_n)$, and $x$ is generated from $X$ by a particular assignment of all random variables in the tuple

Then

$$E_{x\sim p_{data}(x)}[ f(x) ] = \int\limits_{x_1}\int\limits_{x_2}  \cdots \int\limits_{x_n} f(x) p_{data}(x) dx_n \cdots dx_1$$

Is my interpretation exact?  If wrong, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Not all random variables are discrete or continuous.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Do you mean some of them are discrete and others are continuous?

Comment: Some random variables are neither discrete nor continuous. For example, with probability 1/2, return 0, and otherwise, return a value uniformly distributed over [0,1].

Comment: This is probability theory, not probability applied to computer science. So I'm migrating this question to our sister site about mathematics where you're far more likely to get an answer.